# How to handle an error codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

As my address bar comes with,

```
localhost/likeus/index.php/mov/detail/14
```

If I put any other value instead of 14 it will shows blank as we all know there is no data in the database table. But if I put something like `--124*7jlkl=+` or blank it shows an error like this,

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

SQL code:

```
select * 
from list 
where id!=-- and lang = '' and status = '1' order by limit 5
```

> Filename: D:\wamp\wamp\www\likeus\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

In simple php we can do,

```
$select_up = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE id =-=- or someting ";
$result_up = mysql_query($select_up);

if($result_up)
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_up);
else 
{
    header("location:error.php");
}
```

So then how can I handle such an error in CI, please help with it with proper lines of code.

Comment: Related reading: [How to prevent SQL Injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Use ActiveRecord instead of mysql. There is nn reason not to! Mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: What do you really mean by handle the error?

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for each input